# (xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete goes to private sub

Tags: excel, vba

I have a code that filter table by "#N/D!" criteria and then delete visible rows. It all worked well after i added to other sheet a Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal target As Range). Now my macro when it reach below code it goes to this private sub and i dont know why? Someone can explain this?

```
ws.Range("$A$2:$AD$" & LastRow).SpecialCells _
(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this:**

```
Application.EnableEvents = False

ws.Range("$A$2:$AD$" & LastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete

Application.EnableEvents = True
```

Comment: Seems that your solution is working, thank you. Do you have any idea why its jumpign to private sub?

Comment: Yes, Because your selection on that sheet is changing because of deletion, so it triggers that event contained in Private Sub